# How do I install Ubuntu 14.04.02 alongside Windows 8.1?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Where can I find the how-to guide to install Ubuntu 14.04.02 alongside Windows 8.1? Because I don't know anything about it. I have a brand new system with a Core i5 processor.

Comment: What have you tried? What installation instructions did you follow and how did it fail at which step? How did you download Ubuntu and from what media are you trying to boot it off (e.g. USB flash drive, CD-ROM, etc.) Please [edit] your question to include all this kind of information. We can't see your screen and we don't have your computer so we rely completely on the information you put in your question, you see? :)

Comment: In case you are running into issues with booting (UEFI/Secure boot), this Q&A might be of help: http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/88802

Comment: Do you want 14.10 or 14.04?  There is no 14.14!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try out Ubuntu before re-partitioning your system, you can follow this procedure [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

If you are ready to make the plunge, the official Windows Dual Boot documentation is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

Comment: You guys are awesome, yeah im going to try the dual boot flash drive until i learn enough to ditch bill gates. I didn't have a procedure at all and didn't know where to find one yet. Thanks for not judging me!

Comment: My stupic new computer didn't come with a DVD drive, but it has a fake one the side that fooled me in the store!

Comment: If you have a USB stick, or can get one, you could follow the directions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_a_bootable_Ubuntu_USB_flash_drive_from_Windows